# "Merge" two columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sheet with a column with the names of a lot of individuals (there are repetitions) which is of the following type:

```
   Name
Jackson Alan
Wilson Pete
Williamson Tom
...
Williamson Tom
...
Peterson Alan
```

In another sheet I have two columns: one with all these individuals (only once each this time) and another one with a score which is associated to these players:

```
     Name           Score
Williamson Tom       85
     ...
Jackson Alan         90
Wilson Pete          80
Peterson Alan        70
```

I want to associate the score of each person to their name in the first sheet so the result looks like that:

```
  Name             Score
Jackson Alan        90
Wilson Pete         80
Williamson Tom      85
...
Williamson Tom      85
...
Peterson Alan       70
```

Can you recommend me a fast way to do it with pandas in Python for example (the first sheet has about 100k names so I need it to be fast enough). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use merge

```
import pandas as pd
names = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'], columns=['names'])
names_scores = pd.DataFrame([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)], columns=['names', 'scores'])
names.merge(names_scores, left_on='names', right_on='names', how='outer')
```

(you can change how to be 'outer', 'inner', etc. for various join logic)

this will give you

```
  names  scores
0     A       1
1     A       1
2     B       2
3     C       3
```